# Nextjs: running code after complete fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, fetch

This is my code:

```
async function checkAuth() {
    console.log("3")
    await fetch(apiUrl+'/auth', {
        method: 'POST'
    }).then(response => response.json()).then(result => {
        console.log("5")
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log("6")
    })
    console.log("4")
}

function getFirstData() {
    console.log("1");
    checkAuth()
    console.log("2");
}
```

I want to `checkAuth()` run first, and after finish it, another code will be run.

So, my result should be:
13542

But my code not work

Comment: `checkAuth` is an async function, that means it won't wait for its result if you call it without using `await`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
async function getFirstData() {
    console.log("1");
    await checkAuth()
    console.log("2");
}
```